# How to connect with client to my postgres container in docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I'm following this guide:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

I have all set up and running, and I'm trying to figure out how to connect with one of my DB client (Sequel Pro or pgAdmin) to the postgres container.

I also tried to map the postgres port in order to have it served outside from the container (docker-compose.yml), without success:

```
  version: '3'
  services:
    db:
      image: postgres
      ##### Trying this...
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      #####
    web:
      build: .
      command: bundle exec rails s -p 3030 -b '0.0.0.0'
      volumes:
        - .:/myapp
      ports:
        - "3030:3030"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? What version of docker?

Comment: To connect to the postgres container you can run:   "docker-compose exec db postgres".  That will drop you in.

Comment: I want to connect via client not shell.

Comment: @koalaok, execute `docker-compose ps` and make sure your container is running and not exiting. Also post details about your OS?

Comment: Yes it is and executin lsof -i -n I see postgres LISTEN. But no port specified

Comment: Please post (relevant) details of lsof 's output as well your OS and output from 'docker-compose ps'.